# How can I compare two strings in bash?

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to remove all ".s" files in a folder that can be derived by ".c" source files.
This is my code

```
for cfile in *.c; do 
    #replace the last letter with s
    cfile=${cfile/%c/s}
    for sfile in *.s; do
        #compare cfile with sfile; if exists delete sfile
        if [ $cfile==$sfile ]; then
            rm $sfile;
        fi
    done
done
```

But this code deletes all the ".s" files. I think it's not comparing the filenames properly.
Can someone please help.

Comment: You don't need a nested loop here.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to compare strings in bash is:

```
if [ "$string1" == "$string2" ]; then
```

this way if one of the strings is empty it'll still run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
[[ "$cfile" = "$sfile" ]] && rm "$sfile"
```

OR

```
[[ "$cfile" == "$sfile" ]] && rm "$sfile"
```

OR by using old `/bin/[` (test) program

```
[ "$cfile" = "$sfile" ] && rm "$sfile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Saying

```
if [ $chile==$sfile ]; then
```

would **always** be true since it amounts to saying

```
if [ something ]; then
```

**Always** ensure spaces around the operators.

The other problem is that you're saying:

```
cfile=${cfile/%c/s}
```

You probably wanted to say:

```
sfile=${cfile/%c/s}
```

And you need to get rid of the inner loop:

```
for sfile in *.s; do
done
```

Just keep the comparison code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simpliest solution would be:

```
for cfile in *.c ; do rm -f "${cfile%.c}.s" ; done
```

It just lists all the `.c` files and try to delete the corresponding `.s` file (if any).

Answer (score 0):

```
for cFile in *.c; do
    sFile="${cFile%c}s"
    if [[ -f "$sFile" ]]; then
        echo "delete $sFile"
    fi
done
```

The actual deletion of the files I leave as an exercise. :-)

You can also just brute force and delete everything and redirecting the error messages to `/dev/null`:

```
for cFile in *.c; do
    sFile="${cFile%c}s"
    rm "$sFile" &> /dev/null
done
```

but this will be slower of course.

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting a reply if it answered your question.